# TCP session when using Locust tool

Tags: python, connection, load-testing, tcpclient, locust

In my use case, I am using locust to simulate 100 users and each user has a set of tasks (which involves sending HTTP GET requests to different pages of the host). What does a user mean in this case, does it mean that for simulating a user, locust brings up a TCP session between the locust host and the web server and maintains the connection while sending the multiple HTTP requests over that connection? So when locust says 100 users are up, does it mean 100 TCP sessions are up and it is going to use those sessions to send back and forth HTTP request and responses?

Not sure if my understanding of the working of locust is right.

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is correct. Each Locust HttpUser has its own underlying [requests.Session](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#session-objects) object.

Every such object maintains its own TCP/HTTP connection (and cookies), so if you have 10 concurrent users, you will have 10 concurrent connections.

Subsequent task iterations of a User will reuse that same connection.

If you want to, you can also do concurrent requests/connections within a single User, see https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/increase-performance.html#concurrency, but that is a rare use case and probably not what you are asking about.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a good idea to use a load testing tool unless you understand how does it work under the hood and whether it can properly simulate the anticipated usage of the system under test.

One of possible options is looking at documentation, for example [Writing a locustfile](https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/writing-a-locustfile.html) chapter says:

> When a test starts, locust will create an instance of this class for every user that it simulates, and each of these users will start running within their own green gevent thread.
>
> Methods decorated with @task are the core of your locust file. For every running user, Locust creates a greenlet (micro-thread), that will call those methods.
>
> When a task has finished executing, the User will then sleep during its wait time (in this case between 1 and 5 seconds). After its wait time it’ll pick a new task and keep repeating that.

The best way of "understanding" is using a sniffer tool like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/), you can see what exactly is happening on TCP and HTTP levels, compare the network footprint with the real browser (or other application) and amend your Locust configuration accordingly so Locust would send the same number requests of the same nature as the real browser does.

More information: [What Is Locust Load Testing?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/locust-load-testing)